# How to disable DIV tag in a CakePHP submit button?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to disable the div tag but the DIV still showing.

Code:

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->input('Get Taxi',array('div'=>false, 'type'=>'submit', 'id'=>'submit','label'=>false));?>
```

Output:

```
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Taxi" id="submit">
</div>
```

I want to it look without div tag like-

```
    <input type="submit" value="Get Taxi" id="submit">
```

Comment: just like you did 'div' => false should do the trick.. what version of cake do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer

It should be-

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->submit('Get Taxi',array('div'=>false, 'id'=>'submit','label'=>false));?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: You should always go through the docs thoroughly before posting a question here...

Comment: @skywalker first i have tried but i am not getting any solution. So i need help my senior as well he solved my problem. And i post the answer in above. This answer will helps to other people. Thanks.